# combine and replace value dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have two dataframes with the same date and client id, but with a different amount.

I try to get another dataframe with dfA amount value and keep the another 0's on dfB when dfA does not exist

```
dfA:
    client_id  date         amount
0     1        2020-07-11    100
1     1        2020-07-10    90
2     1        2020-07-09    80
3     1        2020-07-12    70
3     1        2020-07-01    86

dfB:
    client_id  date         amount
0     1        2020-07-11    0
1     1        2020-07-10    0
2     1        2020-07-09    0
3     1        2020-07-07    0
4     1        2020-07-06    0
5     1        2020-07-05    0
5     1        2020-07-04    0
3     1        2020-07-03    0
4     1        2020-07-02    0
5     1        2020-07-01    0
```

I want to get:

```
dfResult:
    client_id  date         amount
0     1        2020-07-11    100
1     1        2020-07-10    90
2     1        2020-07-09    80
3     1        2020-07-07    70
4     1        2020-07-06    0
5     1        2020-07-05    0
5     1        2020-07-04    0
3     1        2020-07-03    0
4     1        2020-07-02    0
5     1        2020-07-01    86
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
(
    dfB.date.map(
        dfA.set_index('date')['amount'].to_dict()
    ).fillna(0.0)
)
```

Or

```
(
    dfB.merge(
        dfA, on=['client_id', 'date'], suffixes=("_x", ""), how='left'
    ).fillna(0.0).drop(columns=["amount_x"])
)
```

---

```
   client_id        date  amount
0          1  2020-07-11  100.0
1          1  2020-07-10   90.0
2          1  2020-07-09   80.0
3          1  2020-07-07    0.0
4          1  2020-07-06    0.0
5          1  2020-07-05    0.0
5          1  2020-07-04    0.0
3          1  2020-07-03    0.0
4          1  2020-07-02    0.0
5          1  2020-07-01   86.0
```

Comment: This would ignore the `client_id` which (I guess) is kinda important

Answer (score 1):

You can `concat` the df's together, sort by amount and then drop duplicates.

```
dfResult = pd.concat([dfA,dfB]).sort_values(by='amout',ascending = False).drop_duplicates(subset=['client_id','date'],keep='first').reset_index().sort_values(by=['client id','date'],ascending = (True,False))
```

Comment: hello, sorry aditional TypeError: Cannot compare type 'Timestamp' with type 'date'

Comment: the dfb dataframe

Comment: date_range = pd.date_range(date_begin.date(), date_end.date())
                data = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['client_id', 'date', 'amount'])
                data['date'] = date_range